# How do I kill a tumbleweed?

Tags: cactus-mccoy-2

In [Cactus McCoy 2](http://www.flipline.com/games/cactusmccoy2/index.html), one of the objectives is to kill 6 tumbleweeds:

[image: Tumbler: Destroy all of the tumbleweeds in the area (0/6)]

However, I can't figure out how. I've tried punching, hitting with weapons,shooting weapons, throwing boxes... nothing worked. I can't find anything on the Internet about it either, although that could be my poor searching skills.

**How do I kill a tumbleweed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the wiki entry for tumbleweeds does not explain this, according to [the wiki entry for the challenge itself](http://cactusmccoy.wikia.com/wiki/Tumbler), tumbleweeds can only be damaged by bladed weapons:

> As only blade-like weapons (such as machete) can cut tumbleweed, these weapons need to be obtained first to complete the challenge. You can also complete the challenge the first time you enter the level.